# "Тоска зеленая"

Tags: фразеология

Вот подумалось, а почему, собственно, тоска — зеленая? Ну, зависть черная — это понятно, все черное ассоциируется с негативом. Но зеленый-то цвет — цвет жизни. Так при чем тут тоска?

Comment: По английски, зеленый - цвет зависти ("green with envy")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть версия, что тоска зеленая потому, что зеленый цвет - цвет тины, болота. Еще есть версия (Н.ВАШКЕВИЧА), что это русское выражение от арабского *заъален* (زعل) “переживание, тоска” (мне все-таки болото ближе, потому что наше). Интересно, что у американцев тоска голубая (blue). Отсюда и целое направление в музыке - блюз (blues).

Answer (score 0):

В фильме "Королева бензоколонки" буфетчица советует заправщице бежать с бензоколонки, т.к. летом на бензоколонке тоска зеленая, осенью-тоска желтая, а зимой тоска- белая.Возможно, от этого и пошла тоска зеленая как сокращение от полной фразы буфетчицы.

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы ошибаетесь. **Ни ресторана, ни девочек! Зеленая тоска.** М. А. Булгаков. Бег (1927 год).

Answer (score 0):

«Тоска зелёная» — название депрессивного состояния человека.

Фразеологизм ***тоска зеленая*** употребляется для выражения гнетущего тягостного чувства, душевного томления от безделья, от отсутствия интереса к окружающему, невыносимой скуки.

Специфика употребления прилагательного *зеленый* в русском языке обусловлена его исторической связью со словом ***зелье***, которая связывает это цветообозначение с понятием горечи, чего-либо ядовитого, с тематикой пьянства (Зеленый Змий).
В русском языковом сознании зеленый цвет также ассоциируется с цветом мха, тины, ряски, болота. Тоска затягивает, как болото.

Использованы материалы из статьи И. В. Сироткиной [Языковые средства создания образности фразеологизмов, выражающих печаль, в русском и английском языках](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/yazykovye-sredstva-sozdaniya-obraznosti-frazeologizmov-vyrazhayuschih-pechal-v-russkom-i-angliyskom-yazykah).